# custom font unrecognized in react native ios app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fonts

I'm struggling to get my font, *PressStart2P*, loaded on. Its a font from google fonts. . . Have gone through the following steps, multiple times, to make sure I wasnt sloppy. By all indications, the font should be available in the react native app.

1. created the assets folder at the root of my project directory
2. create the fonts folder within the assets folder and place the font files inside... exactly as the PostScript name indicates, and have used both .otf and .ttf versions of the font.
3. in package.json, specified where the custom fonts are located:

```
 "rnpm": {
   "assets": [
  "./assets/fonts/"
   ]
 },
```

4. in my terminal, entered npx react-native link
5. added my fonts in *App.js*

For reference, here is the entire App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View , TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor:'#e9ffc945',flex: 1,
       justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:26, color: "#85321b45",
        fontFamily: "PressStart2P"}}>Allah'u'Abha :)</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            backgroundColor:'#a4a6fc19',
            padding: 95,
            borderRadius: 19,

          }}
        >
         <Text
           style={{
             color: "white",
             fontSize: 20
           }}
         >
           </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Additionally, I've checked in my copy bundle resources, in my project target in xcode... the file is there. Any ideas out there ?

Comment: Do you Link the assets using ```react-native link```?

Comment: yup, npx react native linked them

Comment: close this question Already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700224/fontfamily-unrecognized-in-react-native-ios-app